# RecyclerView throws null exception when setting it

Tags: java, android, xml

Working on an android project just for the fun of it. I am getting back the error after a user tries to log in. I did a try-catch around the line where the error is and the `RecyclerView` object itself is `null`. So now that I know that, I am trying to figure out why it isn't getting set when I do `findViewById()`. I will paste the relevant code down below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MyProductAdapter myProductAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications).build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listId);
        System.out.println("This is recyclverView" + recyclerView);
        try {
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("null here" + e.getCause());
        }

        ArrayList<MyProduct> myProductData = new ArrayList<>();
        myProductData.add(new MyProduct("Panadol", "Pill  for headAche", "Price : $2.99", R.drawable.logo2));
        myProductData.add(new MyProduct("Nyquill", "Pill  for headAche", "Price : $2.99", R.drawable.logo2));
        myProductData.add(new MyProduct("ZAck", "Pill  for headAche", "Price : $2.99", R.drawable.logo2));
        myProductData.add(new MyProduct("Codeine", "Pill  for headAche", "Price : $2.99", R.drawable.logo2));


        myProductAdapter = new MyProductAdapter(myProductData, MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myProductAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bar, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                myProductAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

`fragment_dashboard.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"

         />




</LinearLayout>
```

`DashBoardFragment.java`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.medistak.R;

public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        dashboardViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        dashboardViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {

            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if the `R.id.listId` already assigned to a `RecyclerVew` in `R.layout.activity_main2`

Comment: Refer to updated code plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit (after OP adds the `DashboardFragment` class)

Move your `MyProductAdapter` and `recyclerView` code from `MainActivity` to `DashboardFragment` `onCreateView()` method as follows:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listId);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(myProductAdapter);
```

---

Your `RecyclerView` `listId` resides in your `DashboardFragment` whereas you are initializing and setting it up in your `MainActivity` class. The reason why `Null Object Reference` error is showing up is because of the order in which `Activities` and their underlying `Fragments` are added to the `Backstack`.

First your `MainActivity` is setup. Then follows the `Fragments` lying in `MainActivity`, in your case its the `DashboardFragment`. So if you will setup a `recyclerView` of the `DashboardFragment` which is not even in existence from `MainActivity's` point of view and yet to be `created` , of course it will lead to a `NPE`.

The solution to your problem will be to pluck out all the `recyclerView` setup code from `MainActivity` class and transfer it over to `DashboardFragment`.

Comment: I have updated my DashBoardFragment class. Please suggest what I should add/delete to it.

Comment: getting `Cannot resolve method findViewById in DashBoardFragment`

Comment: any thoughts @karan dhilon

Comment: You cant directly call `findViewById()` in a fragment. Call `getView().findViewById(<ID>)`.

Comment: thanks alot @karan dhillon